# Make Errors: Missing Includes in C++ Script?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, qmake

I just got help in how to compile this script a few mintues ago on SO but I have managed to get errors. I am only a beginner in C++ and have no idea what the below erros means or how to fix it.

This is the [**script in question**](http://gitorious.org/wkthumb/wkthumb/blobs/master/main.cpp). I have read the comments from some users suggesting they changed the `#include` parts but it seems to be exactly what the script has, [**see this comment**](http://www.insecure.ws/2009/04/02/xserver-less-webpage-screenshot-c#comment-855).

```
[root@localhost wkthumb]# qmake-qt4 && make
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/usr/include -I. -I. -I. -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:5:20: error: QWebView: No such file or directory
main.cpp:6:21: error: QWebFrame: No such file or directory
main.cpp:8: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token
main.cpp:11: error: ‘QWebView’ has not been declared
main.cpp: In function ‘void loadFinished(bool)’:
main.cpp:18: error: ‘view’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:18: error: ‘QWebSettings’ has not been declared
main.cpp:19: error: ‘QWebSettings’ has not been declared
main.cpp:20: error: ‘QWebSettings’ has not been declared
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:42: error: ‘view’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:42: error: expected type-specifier before ‘QWebView’
main.cpp:42: error: expected `;' before ‘QWebView’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I have the web kit on my Fedora Core 10 machine:
qt-4.5.3-9.fc10.i386
qt-devel-4.5.3-9.fc10.i386

Thanks all for any help

Comment: Are you using the same `wkthumb.pro`?

Comment: @gf - Yes, I am. Do I need to modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the compiler cannot find what you're trying to include, i.e. `<QWebView>`.  The way to tell the compiler where to look is with the `-I` flag, to specify include directories (these are not recursive).

Currently, you set the following include dirs:

- -I/usr/lib/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++
- -I.
- -I/usr/include/QtCore
- -I/usr/include/QtGui
- -I/usr/include

You need to find where `QWebView` is located on your system, and add the include path to the commandline (or install QWebView into one of the above dirs).

General note:  When you get a lot of errors like this, focus on the first one or two.  The later errors (such as `‘QWebView’ has not been declared`) will probably be solved by fixing the missing-include error.

Answer (score 0):

```
main.cpp:18: error: ‘view’ was not declared in this scope
```

Looks like namespaces have to be provided in the code. Read on namespaces.

```
main.cpp:20: error: ‘QWebSettings’ has not been declared
```

No type definition available, can be missing include.

Comment: *"QWebView: No such file or directory"* - the web view include files are not found.

Comment: Corrolary: The **first** error always is the important one. I usually don't even look at the subsequent errors, as they are usually follow-up errors that vanish when the cause of the first error is resolved.